# Android Listview simpleadapter onClick, how to find which view was clickon?

Tags: android, onclick, textview, simpleadapter

I have a list view that is built using a simpleAdapter, each row is defined by a Layout containing a TableRow and a few TextView.

What should I do to know on which TextView (in the layout) was clicked on?

I am able to get the listview row (position) if I use a OnItemClickListener on the Listview, however it dosen't tell me on which TextView on that row was clicked on.

I would like to take different action depending on which TextView a user click on in a listview

```
listview

-----------------------
TextView1 : TextView2 |     <--Row1
-----------------------
TextView1 : TextView2 |     <--Row2
-----------------------
TextView1 | TextView2 |     <--Row3
-----------------------
```

I would like to be able to tell, that row 2's TextView2 was click on.

Hopefully I am explaining myself well enough.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the click is being handled by `onItemClick`, then you cannot know from this which `View` WITHIN that `View` was clicked. An `OnItemClickListener` just handles clicking a list item. What you might try is using a custom `adapter` in which you grab hold of all the Views in the row in `getView()` and set `onClickListeners` on them there. Or you can define the `onClickListeners` directly in your `View` class if possible.

Answer (score 3):

you can use below code in  your List Activity

```
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.your name, String Name));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the click of different view's in Adapter.The Adapter must be customized

Comment: Can you be more specific in which way the adapter need to be customized, or possibly point me to an example. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar to set a tag on elements within the list view, so I could find which button was clicked

```
    myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myArrayList, R.layout.list_item,
    new String[] {"ItemID", "ItemText", "ItemImage"},
    new int[] {R.id.item_id, R.id.item_text, R.id.item_image})
    {
    @Override
      public View getView (int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.findViewById(R.id.item_id).setTag(row);
        view.findViewById(R.id.item_text).setTag(row);
        view.findViewById(R.id.item_image).setTag(row);
        return view;
      }
    };
```

I added an onClick event for each item in the layout

```
<TextView
   ...
   android:clickable="true"
   android:onClick="myClickEvent"
   ...
/>
```

And then in my onClick events I had something like

```
public void myClickEvent(View v) {
  Object o = v.getTag();
  if (o instanceof Integer) {
    int row = (Integer) o;
    // do something
  }
```

You can either use one onClick event per item in the view to determine which item was clicked, or you can have one onClick event for all and modify the tag to contain both the item and the row.